# SAS query builder - extracting text after duplicate delimeters

Tags: sas, find, scanf, query-builder, substr

Good afternoon,

Hopefully Quite a simple one. I have a column of strings, similar to the following but of differing lengths:

```
1001_Q10_1
```

They all follow the same rule, `"code_Qnumber_Response"`

I am trying to create 2 columns, `Code, QNumber, Response`

So far I have got:

```
Code: 1001
Qnumber: Q10
```

But not the response.

Depending on the Q this can go up to response option 10, so double digits, I can't just take the last character

Anybody know how to do this in SAS query builder?

Regards,
Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use scan?

```
data want;
    string   = '1001_Q10_1';

    code     = input(scan(string, 1, '_'), 8.);
    qnumber  = input(compress(scan(string, 2, '_'), 'Q'), 8.);
    response = input(scan(string, 3, '_'), 8.);
run;
```

Output:

```
code    qnumber response
1001    10      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you've already done it in Query builder, perhaps by using substr?
If so this may help:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select
    code_Qnumber_Response
    ,substr(code_Qnumber_Response,1,4) as Code
    ,substr(code_Qnumber_Response,6,3) as QNumber
    ,substr(code_Qnumber_Response,10 ) as Response
    from have;
quit;
```

Output:

```
code_Qnumber_Response   Code    QNumber   Response
1001_Q10_1              1001    Q10       1
1001_Q10_3              1001    Q10       3
1001_Q10_10             1001    Q10       10
```

This solution may be good for you if you are more familiar with substr().
To get the response you simply don't tell the substr() how many characters to keep, and it'll keep all of the characters from position 10 onwards:

```
substr(code_Qnumber_Response,10 ) as Response
```